# Able to scroll without using a fixed height?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have page which usses CSS transitions to slide from one section to the next. However I have the height set 100% and an overflow so that the slides fill the screen.  However this means that if the content is longer the page you cannot see it.

I have created a JSFiddle which you can see it at http://jsfiddle.net/6mesm/

```
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    overflow-x: hidden;overflow-y: visible;
}

.pt-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.pt-page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

What is the best way to be able to fix the scroll problem without fixing the heights, so that the background colours still fill the whole screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there something wrong with using a fixed height? Leaving the `height: 100%;` and setting `overflow: auto` on `.pt-page` allows the pages to scroll if they're too long.

Comment: Thanks! I think i was massively over thinking this. Haha